# Delete Image when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to write a page that has images and when they are clicked they will disappear. I keep getting ".addEventListener is not a function". What am I doing wrong/missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
        <img src="https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/article_main_large/public/dogs_16x9_0.jpg?itok=byPuhQjh" id = "img" />
        <img src="https://www.yvr.ca/-/media/yvr/blog/2018/57_yvr_puppies_2018.jpg" id = "img" />

      <script text = "javascript">
      let image_node = document.createElement('img');
      img.addEventListener('click', () => {
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img);

      });

      </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because you don't have any variable called 'img' in your script. You should first get all the elements with tag 'img'([some help](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)), then iterate over them and add your event listener to each one of them

Comment: I think you want to simply do `image_node.addEventListener()` and `.removeChild(image_node)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id property must be unique for each tag (in your case, each `img` tag).

After naming each tag with an unique ID, you can get them with javascript with **document.getElementById(id)**. Then you can use **remove()** to exclude these tags.

I made some modifications at your code. See if it is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img
      src="https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/article_main_large/public/dogs_16x9_0.jpg?itok=byPuhQjh"
      id="first-img"
    />
    <img
      src="https://www.yvr.ca/-/media/yvr/blog/2018/57_yvr_puppies_2018.jpg"
      id="second-img"
    />

    <script text="javascript">
      let firstImage = document.getElementById("first-img");
      let secondImage = document.getElementById("second-img");
      firstImage.addEventListener("click", () => {
        firstImage.remove();
      });
      secondImage.addEventListener("click", () => {
        secondImage.remove();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure about what you're going to do, I think you can do what you want by doing adding an event listener. Here is an example:

```
const image = document.querySelector("img");
const imgView = true;

function handleImgClick() {
    if (imgView == true) {
        image.style.display = "none";
        imgView = false;
    } else {
        image.style.display = "inline-block";
        imgView = true;
    }
}

image.addEventListener("click",handleImgClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to all clicks in the body and remove the target it is a IMG tag.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    e.target.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("#images img");

images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#images img {
  width: 323.6‬px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?3">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?4">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?5">
</div>
```